# HTML Table Auto Fill space

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following css and html.  Question is if the middle td does not contain content or text can the left and right td use the space, so 50/50  or if only one td has content or text then it should take 100% of the space.  Is this possible?  Or is it possible with jquery or javascript?

```css
<style type="text/css">
table.threecol-layout > tbody > tr > td {
   width: 33%;
  } 
</style>
```

```html
<table class="threecol-layout">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="lcol">
                left-column
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="ccol">
                
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="rcol">
                right-column
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you will need javascript for that. i don't think is possible with pure css/html

Comment: Here's a CSS/HTML JSFiddle you can experiment with, and it's close. http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/fpvv321y/ The table is set to 100% width, and the td widths (along with any padding, margins, or borders) were removed. Even if you remove the content from a cell, if there is padding or formatting that has size, it will take up a bit of room. Also experiment with adding various amounts of content to the cells, to see how the cells divide their width and height.

Comment: @Talkingrock - thanks.  When there is content in the 3 td's each need to use equal space (i.e. 33.33% each).  Does this happen automatically using the css/html given?  Do the p tags make this happen?

Comment: Unfortunately when you add a size to a td, it will display even if it doesn't contain any content. If you add a size to an element within the cell, like a paragraph, it will be the percent of the cell size, not the table. If the contents of the cells are about the same, then the cell sizes will adapt themselves be more or less equal. If the content size varies, the cells will display according to the amount of content. Since you need exact sizes (33.33%, 50%, 100%), perhaps  jQuery or Javascript will give the most consistent results.